# Firing in multiple directions at once. (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a top down shooter game in unity using the old input system and I ran into a problem. I use the arrow keys to shoot but I'm not sure how to fire in multiple directions at the same time/frame.
Code:

```C#
void Update()
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        //input section
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            ShootUp();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            ShootDown();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            ShootLeft();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            ShootRight();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            ShootUp();
            ShootRight();
        }

 }
```

I thought that looking at both arrow keys at the same time, I would just call both functions as well. Its does not work however.
I tried google but it's pretty hard to find info on the old input system having the same problem.
Edit for clarification

```
public void SpawnBullet(Vector3 direction, Quaternion rotation)
{
    //fire rate correction
    if (currentTime < currentFireRate) { return; };
    currentTime = 0;
    //bullet spawning and firing
    Bullet instanceOfBullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab);
    instanceOfBullet.transform.position = transform.position;
    instanceOfBullet.direction = direction;
    instanceOfBullet.transform.rotation = rotation;
    instanceOfBullet.tag = "Player Bullet";
    
}

void ShootUp()
{
    SpawnBullet(Vector3.up, Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0));
    //Debug.Log("bullet");
}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. I just tossed it into my update and logged the results and it notified me of every key press or combination of keypresses.

Try logging your results too.

Also, you're going to shoot 4 times if you check "if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))" with  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) and  "if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))"

That may be causing your issue

Comment: Your last if has no reason to exist. If UpArrow and RightArrow are down, it should already enter their respective if-scopes. Could you add what actually happens in ShootUp and ShootRight? To make sanity checks, add log-statements within the ifs and/or use the debugger to step through the code.

Comment: This completely depends on what exactly `ShootUp`, `ShootRight` etc are doing! Could you include them here? Please provide more details and describe the actual desired behavior. E.g. do you really want to shoot multiple times or rather once but in diagonal directions?

Comment: I want to shoot in both directions simultaneously, and code has been added, ShootRight is almost exactly the same as shoot up just with a Vector3.right, Quaternion.Euler(0,0,270)

Answer (score 0):

*Updated answer*
The problem is that currentTime becomes 0 al in the first method, and in the next method, being less than currentFireRate, the method stops by not instantiating anything.

To solve this, I created a Coroutine that takes an Action as a parameter, that is any code snippet.
Start this coroutine after checking if currentTime is less than currentFireRate, and give it as an update the code instruction that assigns currentTime the value 0.
The coroutine first waits for a frame, and then invokes the action, executing the indicated code (in our case set currentTime equal to 0).
In this way, if you press two keys while executing the method to instantiate the bullet twice, the value of currentTime will not set to 0 before the end of the frame and therefore both will be executed.

```
    void Update()
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        //input section
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            ShootUp();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            ShootDown();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            ShootLeft();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            ShootRight();
        }
    }

    public void SpawnBullet(Vector3 direction, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        //fire rate correction
        if (currentTime < currentFireRate) { return; };
        StartCoroutine(DoActionAfterAFrame(() => currentTime = 0));
        //bullet spawning and firing
        Bullet instanceOfBullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab);
        instanceOfBullet.transform.position = transform.position;
        instanceOfBullet.direction = direction;
        instanceOfBullet.transform.rotation = rotation;
        instanceOfBullet.tag = "Player Bullet";

    }

    void ShootUp()
    {
        SpawnBullet(Vector3.up, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
    }

    IEnumerator DoActionAfterAFrame(System.Action _action)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        _action.Invoke();
    }
```

I hope I have helped you :)

Comment: A) the paraphrasing of the code is really completely unnecessary imho ^^ B) your answer is purely based on assumptions about what exactly happens in within the different shoot methods! If they e.g. somewhere do something like `transform.forward = Vector3.up;` vs `transform.forward = Vector3.right;` in order to make the object look into according direction then calling both methods will still overrule each other and apply only the last one

Comment: Sorry for my bad English :). You are right: I tried to give an answer without considering what methods contain here.

Comment: derHugo is exactly right I have functions call SpawnBullet and pass through the vector3 Direction. How would I change it so that it could do both?

Comment: I also added the extra code to the main post.

Comment: Hey I tried what you said but I get an error from VS saying that WaitForEndOfFrame is a non-invokable member and connot be used as a method.

Comment: it’s very strange. Does Unity give you nay error? Did you add “using System.Collections;”? Can you save it and try on Unity?

Comment: If you replace "WaitForEndOfFrame()", con "WaitForSeconds(1)", does it still give the error? Even trying this code gives you the error? void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoActionAfterAFrame(() => print(“hello")));
    }
    IEnumerator DoActionAfterAFrame(System.Action _action)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        _action.Invoke();
    }

Comment: I changed it and same error, and I cannot try in the unity editor because Unity will not run if there are syntax errors.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, so first of all. All of these should go into a seperate method and then called in Update. Secondly, Input.GetAxis use that, and write a method which would take a Vector2 direction and instantiate a bullet towards that direction.

```
private void Update()
{
   currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
   Shooting();
}

private void Shooting()
{
   var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
   var y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
   Vector2 direction = new Vector2(x, y);
   
}

private void Shoot(Vector2 direction)
{
   // Instantiate bullets and fire them towards direction.
}
```

Google Input.GetAxis method, and Vector2 in case you do not know that.

Comment: There is no reason for the original poster to create a new function if the original poster does not want to or is not required to by their stakeholders. And if they were then that new function should exist inside of the Update method and not outside since it should never be called outside of Update. Also, the original poster wants to shoot in 2 directions at once, your method will shoot once and it will include diagonal shots as well. Not to mention the original poster does not want to get axis of the input they specifically want to force the user to use the arrow keys.

Comment: @Displayname true, until OP provides us with further information about the actual desired behavior it is not possible / doesn't make sense to provide any answer

Comment: Correct I do not want to use getaxis, I do want to force arrow keys. I do appreciate the post though.